# Add a class in an anchor tag within a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

does anyone know how Can I add a class in the A tag:

```
<a href="/souscription/digital-vie">Subscribe</a>
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="module" id="prod-subscription">
    <div class="entity entity-bean bean-ap-bl-instruct contextual-links-region block container">
        <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
            <a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a>
            <ul class="contextual-links">
                <li class="bean- first last">
                    <a href="/block/souscription/edit?destination=node/3719"> bloc</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>simple<span>in 3 </span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <span>1</span><p>text</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>2</span><p>texte testx</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>3</span><p>and text</p>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="/souscription/digital-vie">Subscribe</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add some id on these dom elements?

Comment: id="prod-subscription" in the main div !

Comment: I meant on the target anchor itself, so solution will be simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$('a[href="/souscription/digital-vie"]').addClass('classHere');
```

or

```
$('div#prod-subscription a[href="/souscription/digital-vie"]').addClass('classHere');
```

or

```
$('a[href="/souscription/digital-vie"]:contains("Subscribe")').addClass('classHere');
```

```js
$('a[href="/souscription/digital-vie"]:contains("Subscribe")').addClass('classHere');
```

```css
.classHere{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="module" id="prod-subscription">
    <div class="entity entity-bean bean-ap-bl-instruct contextual-links-region block container">
        <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
            <a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a>
            <ul class="contextual-links">
                <li class="bean- first last">
                    <a href="/block/souscription/edit?destination=node/3719"> bloc</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>simple<span>in 3 </span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <span>1</span><p>text</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>2</span><p>texte testx</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>3</span><p>and text</p>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="/souscription/digital-vie">Subscribe</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a solution

Comment: @Mamadou I'm glad it helped .. Good Luck to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and filter the link where the exact text is 'Subscribe' (this may cause problems if you have multiple links with that exact text)

```js
$('a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === 'Subscribe';
}).addClass('new-class');
```

```css
.new-class {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/souscription/digital-vie">Subscribe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question. Do you just want to give the anchor tag a class? That can be done as simply as `<a class="your_class" href="your_link">Subscribe</a>`

Comment: Sorry, in jquery I mean. target the A of my dom and add a class xxx